# Certificate chain not found, but keystore contains private key

Tags: java, android, certificate, keytool, jarsigner

Im trying to sign my apk so I can release an update to my app with this command: `jarsigner ­-verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -­digestalg SHA1 ­-keystore my­release-key.keystore CordovaApp­release­unsigned.apk alias_name` but getting this error:

```
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: ¡sigalg.  ¡sigalg must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

I´ve just moved to a new computer so I copied my .keystore file to it. When I do `keytool -list -v` it seems like it contains the private key, so I dont understand whats wrong.. Is the public key missing?
[image]

Comment: Obviously you didn't type the command correctly in the first place. Why else would `isigalg.` be treated as an alias name?

Comment: See my new answer, could that be the case?

Comment: Where the minus signs went is irrelevant. The facts are that the response you got indicated a problem with the command line; that they are missing from what you posted; and that they are required as stated in @Omikron's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously it was an encoding issue. The command contained characters that looked similar to a minus sign (ASCII code 0x2D), but actually were one of the many dash or hyphen characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).

Because of the wrong character code the first parameter "`-verbose`" was recognised by jarsigner not as an option but as the name of the jar file and "`-sigalg`" was recognised as the alias:

```
Usage: jarsigner [options] jar-file alias
```

This explains why the alias in the error message was "`¡sigalg`" and not the actual alias from the command and contained an inverted exclamation mark at the beginning (this used to be the "-" in another character set).

Comment: Thanks! but the minus signs only disapeared in stackoverflow for some reason :/